# Возникает ошибка ExceptionInInitializerError: Caused by: NoSuchMethodException: DefaultSourceDirectorySet.<init>

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle

При сборке проекта возникает ошибка в строке:

```
apply plugin: "kotlin-android"
```

**Стектрейс ошибки:**

```
Build file 'D:\User\Test_tasks\Example\explorer-github\app\build.gradle' line: 3
    
    A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
    > java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (no error message)
    
    * Try:
    Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Exception is:
    org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.lambda$apply$0(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:133)
        at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:136)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:43)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:250)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:277)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:249)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:42)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:35)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:100)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:250)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$withProjectLock$3(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:310)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:213)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withProjectLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:310)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:291)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:249)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:723)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:150)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:41)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:69)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(DefaultProjectsPreparer.java:46)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.java:64)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer$ConfigureBuild.run(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:40)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.prepareProjects(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:226)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doClassicBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:164)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:125)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:71)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:213)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:67)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:56)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.runClientAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:90)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:86)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:104)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:67)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.sources.DefaultKotlinSourceSet.<init>(DefaultKotlinSourceSet.kt:56)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.sources.DefaultKotlinSourceSetFactory.doCreateSourceSet(KotlinSourceSetFactory.kt:81)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.sources.DefaultKotlinSourceSetFactory.doCreateSourceSet(KotlinSourceSetFactory.kt:48)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.sources.KotlinSourceSetFactory.create(KotlinSourceSetFactory.kt:26)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.sources.KotlinSourceSetFactory.create(KotlinSourceSetFactory.kt:18)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.FactoryNamedDomainObjectContainer.doCreate(FactoryNamedDomainObjectContainer.java:93)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.create(AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.java:78)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.create(AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.maybeCreate(AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.java:65)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AbstractAndroidProjectHandler$handleProject$1.execute(KotlinPlugin.kt:650)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AbstractAndroidProjectHandler$handleProject$1.execute(KotlinPlugin.kt:616)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication$1.execute(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:100)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1.run(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:95)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction.execute(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:92)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:163)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AbstractAndroidProjectHandler.handleProject(KotlinPlugin.kt:648)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinAndroidPlugin$Companion.applyToTarget(KotlinPlugin.kt:603)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinAndroidPlugin.apply(KotlinPlugin.kt:564)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinAndroidPlugin.apply(KotlinPlugin.kt:556)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinBasePluginWrapper.apply(KotlinPluginWrapper.kt:77)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinBasePluginWrapper.apply(KotlinPluginWrapper.kt:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.applyImperative(ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.RuleBasedPluginTarget.applyImperative(RuleBasedPluginTarget.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.addPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:177)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.access$100(DefaultPluginManager.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager$AddPluginBuildOperation.run(DefaultPluginManager.java:272)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.lambda$doApply$0(DefaultPluginManager.java:157)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:156)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:136)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyType(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:167)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:98)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:190)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:49)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.java:37)
        at org.gradle.api.Script$apply.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at build_1khm5ur2kqbvt9hhwhzpw3lkz.run(D:\User\Test_tasks\Example\explorer-github\app\build.gradle:3)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
        ... 140 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet.<init>(java.lang.String, org.gradle.api.internal.file.FileResolver, org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTreeFactory)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.sources.DefaultKotlinSourceSetKt.<clinit>(DefaultKotlinSourceSet.kt:148)
        ... 199 more
```

**Файл build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

apply plugin: "kotlin-android"

apply plugin: "kotlin-android-extensions"

apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"

ext {
    libs_ver = "28.0.0"
    retrofit_ver = "2.5.0"
    picasso_ver = "2.71828"
    gson_ver = "2.8.5"
    room_ver = "1.1.1"
    lifecycle_ver = "1.1.1"
    dagger_ver = "2.20"
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hbvhuwe.explorergithub"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionName "1.2.2"
        versionCode 120002
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField("String", "applicationClientId", explorer_github_app_id)
            resValue("string", "application_client_id", explorer_github_app_id)

            buildConfigField("String", "applicationClientSecret", explorer_github_app_secret)
            resValue("string", "application_client_secret", explorer_github_app_secret)
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")

            buildConfigField("String", "applicationClientId", explorer_github_app_id)
            resValue("string", "application_client_id", explorer_github_app_id)

            buildConfigField("String", "applicationClientSecret", explorer_github_app_secret)
            resValue("string", "application_client_secret", explorer_github_app_secret)
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0'
    kapt 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.5.1'
    //Dagger
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_ver"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_ver"
    compileOnly 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'
    //Room
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.3'
    kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.3'
    //Kotlin
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    //Retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_ver"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_ver"
    //Picasso
    implementation "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:$picasso_ver"
    //Gson
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$gson_ver"
    //support library
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.2.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.3'
    //JUnit
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Kotlin в проекте: 1.3.11
Kotlin в Android Studio: [212-1.7.10-release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spSSd.png)
Gradle wrapper: [7.0.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIynp.png)
Android gradle plugin: [7.0.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIynp.png)

Comment: Какая у вас версия Kotlin и версия Gradle?

Comment: Если собираете проект из Android Studio, то посмотрите, какая у вас версия плагина Kotlin, совпадает ли эта версия с тем, что у вас указано в проекте?

Comment: @Vadik, версия Gradle 7.0.2 (но я её менял с намного более старой), версию плагина Kotlin пока что найти не получается

Comment: Версию плагина Kotlin можно посмотреть в Tools -> Kotlin -> Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates. А версия Kotlin в вашем проекте — это вам надо найти, где у вас в gradle файлах объявляется переменная `kotlin_version` (приложите build.gradle корневого модуля)

Comment: @Vadik, плагин, вроде, нашёл (добавил скрин в вопрос)  с kotlin_version есть строка  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

Comment: Обычно в проекте несколько файлов `build.gradle`: один в корне проекта, а другие в модулях, например, в `app/build.gradle`.

Comment: @Vadik, я поменял Gradle JDK и A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. > java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (no error message) сменилось на A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.sources.DefaultKotlinSourceSetKt, я поменял Gradle JDK обратно, но ошибка A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.sources.DefaultKotlinSourceSetKt осталась

Comment: @Vadik, нашёл -     ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11'

Comment: Добавьте все детали вопроса в сам вопрос, нажав кнопку [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1436935/edit), комментарии не предназначены для стектрейсов, так ничего не понятно. И укажите **в самом вопросе** 1) версию котлин в вашем проекте 2) версию котлин-плагина в Android Studio 3) версию gradle-wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такое [может происходить](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53859608) из-за того, что версия Kотлин в вашем проекте не совпадает с версией Котлин-плагина в Android Studio. Выровняйте версии Kotlin и перезапустите сборку проекта.

Comment: я поменял ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11' на ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0', теперь узказывает на строку buildConfigField("String", "applicationClientId", explorer_github_app_id) и пишет Build file 'D:\User\Test_tasks\Example\explorer-github\app\build.gradle' line: 30

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not get unknown property 'explorer_github_app_id' for BuildType_Decorated{name=debug, debuggable=true...

Comment: я добавил текст ошибки в вопрос

Comment: Версия Kotlin в Android Studio у вас 1.7.10. Она должна совпадать с версией Kotiln в вашем проекте: `ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'`, иначе это может привести к непредсказуемым ошибкам. Если версия языка в проекте у вас изменится, то, возможно, вам нужно будет адаптировать ваш проект под новую версию языка Kotlin. Исходная ошибка, на которую я писал вам ответ это `ExceptionInInitializerError: Caused by: NoSuchMethodException: DefaultSourceDirectorySet.<init>`. Если у вас сейчас другая ошибка, то заводите новый вопрос.